# Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql, база-данных

В текстбоксах задаю некоторые данные. После проделанных манипуляций выдает `incorrect syntax near 'example_of_text1''example_of_text2''example_of_text3'`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Хаме\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication10\WindowsFormsApplication10\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
    SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();
{
public partial class regstud : Form
{


    public regstud()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Students values('" + textBox1.Text + "''" + textBox2.Text + "''" + textBox3.Text + "''" + textBox4.Text + "''" + textBox5.Text + "' ",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sa.Fill(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        finally { con.Close(); }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Запятые между значениями кто будет ставить, Пушкин?

Answer (score 1):

**Никогда**, пожалуйста, **никогда** не конкатенируйте строки в SQL запросе.

Просто используйте [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   @"insert into Students values(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4, @value5)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value5", textBox5.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Естественно, используйте звучные названия.

Так же следует учесть, что `null` как значение быть не может. Если требуется передать "ничто", то следует указать `DBNull.Value` как значение параметра:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", DBNull.Value);
```

Если вам требуется передать объект, но вы **не уверены**, что он **не может быть `null`**, вы можете использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", canBeNullObject ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Эта конструкция читается как "если `canBeNullObject == null`, вставь `DBNull.Value`".

PS. Спасибо @Qwertiy за комментарии.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но текст в TextBox никогда не бывает null :)

Comment: @Qwertiy точно, по привычке ляпнул, спасибо :)

Comment: А может стоило оставить, для наглядности?

Comment: @Qwertiy дополнил, спасибо

Comment: Вообще отлично!

Comment: Иногда `AddWithValue` может вызывать проблемы: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, ошибка в строке:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Students values('" + textBox1.Text + "''" + textBox2.Text + "''" + textBox3.Text + "''" + textBox4.Text + "''" + textBox5.Text + "' ",con);
```

Синтаксис оператора INSERT предполагает разделение списка значений запятыми, кроме того, в конце пропущена закрывающая скобка.

ИМХО, корректный вариант этой строки кода такой:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Students values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "') ",con);
```